# Will the updates mirrored to my local repository get deleted after upgradation?

Tags: apt-mirror

I have mirrored ubuntu repository to my local through apt-mirror tool. A cronjob is set to sync everyday.

My doubt is , are the updates which are there in my local will get removed if its removed from ubuntu archive.

Answer (score 1):

The `apt-mirror` configuration can include an optional `clean` section, which tells `apt-mirror` to look for files which can be deleted. If you have such a section, it will generate a script called `clean.sh` in the `var` directory, which *you must manually 
run* for files to be deleted.

So the packages will be deleted if:

1. You have a `clean` section in your `mirror.list`
2. You run the generated `clean.sh` script.

If you have enabled `clean`, then the output of `apt-mirror` will include something like the following towards the end:

```
3.2 GiB in 429 files and 0 directories can be freed.
Run /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/clean.sh for this purpose.
```